# Eeek! My orphans have no names!

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, profile-page, orphaned-wiki

[image]

These [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/533358) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/533357) don't have a name in my profile page, but on their detail it clearly states that they are an orphaned tag wiki. Can we fix this inconsistency please?

Comment: If you were really smart you'd have edited the image to be the email of some annoying jerk you wanted to spam.

Comment: @Servy yeah, but that's too much work. And I don't really hate anyone, except for Skeet for stealing all my rep :)

Comment: Which is what you want us to think, so that we'll send the spam emails to your (fake) address.

Comment: @Servy just what I need - more viagra offers!

Comment: Orphans? Viagra? Should this be moved to parenting?